# Lunr - gatsby-plugin-lunr - Can I alter data / index on build?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, sanity, lunrjs

I've got a Gatsy-Sanity project that needs a search component. For this I though of using [gatsby-plugin-lunr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-lunr). I run into a problem that my nodes are multilingual. For example one of my fields is constructed like:

```
         "title": {
            "_type": "localeString",
            "nl": "Begin ",
            "en": "Home "
         },
```

(This parser is, in short, like following. If has key `_type` that starts with 'locale*', than return only value of key en or nl. This is passed by a var)

I could make a parser that splits/strips the data. I've got this sort of working (not yet succesfull) inside the  component that runs the search query from the search-index. But that would mean it parses it each search. Is there a way to do this on build in `gatsby-node.js` with a lunr plugin?  I also need this since I would need to add a language prefix on the slug/path of the result.

```
const SearchProcess = lunr => builder => {
  // how to pre-process data
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you do this in the resolvers section of the `gatsby-plugin-lunr` config?

Comment: @ksav, the thing is that it that each node/doc is multilingual. So there is no conditional filtering there.

Comment: I think I'm looking for something like a hook or method between data query/receipt and writing it to the index json. To intercept it and alter the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going with a different gatsby plugin. [gatsby-plugin-local-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-local-search)
This plugin is able to alter the data before saving it with `normalizer` Now I can call a method to conditional alter the data per language.